# simple directive to add class doesn't work

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-directive

I wand to add a class to a `div` based on two condidions. For this I created a directive like this:

```
import { Directive, HostBinding, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: '[confirmdialog-style]',
})
export class ConfirmDialogStyleDirective {
  @Input() isMsgDialog!: boolean;
  @Input() dialogType!: string;

  @HostBinding('class')
  elementClass = this.isMsgDialog ? 'x-' + this.dialogType : '';
}
```

And I use it like this:

```
<div
  class="x-dialog-container"
  confirmdialog-style
  [isMsgDialog]="isMsgDialog"
  [dialogType]="dialogType"
>
```

I set the `isMsgDialog` and `dialogType` properties in the parent component via button click. The two input properties are set correctly, as I checked it via chrome debug tools.

The issue is, that the desired class (f. e. `x-danger`) isn't added to the `div`. Why doesn't this work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this, so that the it takes into account `isMsgDialog` and `dialogType` changes:

```ts
    @HostBinding('class')
    get elementClass() {
        return this.isMsgDialog ? 'x-' + this.dialogType : '';
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, that did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

I find your code is good and I think it is necessary to verify isMsgDialog is not empty